# Any useful difference between std::bit_cast and std::start_lifetime_as?

Tags: c++, c++20, std, type-punning, bit-cast

`std::bit_cast` is apparently being introduced in c++20. and `std::start_lifetime_as` is proposed for c++23 (from [P0593R5](https://wg21.link/p0593R5)).  As they appear to both require that the datatypes involved be trivial anyways, will there be any need for the former once the latter is introduced?

Apologies in advance for not providing any more information about these new features.  I only just heard about them after watching a cppcon 2019 lecture on type-punning, and I wasn't able to find much about `start_lifetime_as` with google.  I'm hoping someone else who sees this might know more.

Comment: You mean, besides the fact that one of them exists as a fully adopted part of the C++20 working draft, while the other is a proposal which is in flux, not adopted as part of any standard, and thus may never be standard?

Comment: @NicolBolas `start_lifetime_as` is proposed for C++23, afaik.

Comment: @NicolBolas Added link to it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer is trivial: `bit_cast` returns a value, whereas `start_lifetime_as` “alters” memory (in a way that exists in the abstract machine but is not expected to affect any physical bits).  You use the former to (once) interpret an existing object as a set of bits; you use the latter to (permanently) interpret existing bits as an object.

Comment: Does the lifetime of the source object end after `start_lifetime_as` execution end? If so, trying to refer (mention) with the old pointer variable is ill-formed or only accessing is ill-formed?

Comment: @sandthorn: The lifetime of any object whose storage overlaps the new object's storage ends ([basic.life]/1.5) unless the new object is nested within it (either because you recreated a subobject exactly or because a storage array was involved: [intro.object]/4).  Pointers to out-of-lifetime objects have special rules ([basic.life]/6).

Comment: If the new `start_lifetime_as` **only** depends on UB lifetime rules like that, it is kind of scary. \[[**LIVE**](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/Psabndxfb)] That is the compiler can't help one who might forget the lifetime rules. It would be more secure if `start_lifetime_as` could invoke ill-formed when misused.

Comment: @sandthorn: If it were possible to implement that, we wouldn't need the function in the first place.

Answer (score 15):

`std::bit_cast` *copies* the bits of its argument to a new value of a different type.

```
float myFloat = 3.14;
auto asUint = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(myFloat);
auto asBytes = std::bit_cast<std::array<char,4>>(myFloat);
```

`myFloat`, `asUint` and `asBytes` are separate variables with separate addresses. The compiler may be able to optimise some them away completely, but logically they are completely distinct values that just happen to have the same size and bits.

`std::start_lifetime_as` doesn't *do* anything. It just informs the compiler that it can treat a range of memory as if it contained an array of the specified type. This then allows the developer to use that memory as an array without triggering undefined behaviour. It doesn't physically modify the memory passed to it and it doesn't return anything. It's purely for C++ object model bookkeeping.

Edit: Robert Leahy has an [excellent presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbkQG09grFw) explaining the problems these functions were created to solve and how they are implemented.

Comment: Would this mean that, for instance, if there was a union of two trivial types of identical size where the bit patterns for one is a valid bit pattern for the other, that you can assign one member of the union, invoke std::start_lifetime_as on the union instance it for the other type, and then access it from the second member without UB?