# How to do type punning correctly in C++

Tags: c++, memcpy, reinterpret-cast, type-punning

Let's say I have this code:

```
//Version 1
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    uint32_t bits{0x3dfcb924}; //bits describe "0.1234" as IEEE 754 floating point
    float num {*((float*) &bits)};
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
```

All I want is to interpret the bits from the `bits` variable as a float. I came to understand that this is called "type punning".

The above code currently works on my machine with GCC 10 on Linux.

I have used this method to "reinterpret bits" for quite some time. However, recently I learned about the "strict aliasing rule" from this post:

[What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

What I took away from there: Two pointers that point to objects of different types (for example `uint32_t*` and `float*`) produce undefined behaviour. So... is my code example above undefined behaviour?

I searched for a way to do it "correctly" and came across this post:

[What is the modern, correct way to do type punning in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67636231/what-is-the-modern-correct-way-to-do-type-punning-in-c)

The accepted answer just tells us "just use `std::memcpy`" and if the compiler supports it (mine doesn't) use "`std::bit_cast`"

I have also searched some other forums and read through some lengthy discussions (most of which were above my level of knowledge) but most of them agreed: Just use `std::memcpy`.

So... do I do it like this instead?

```
//Version 2
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    uint32_t bits{0x3dfcb924}; 
    float num {};
    std::memcpy(&num, &bits, sizeof(bits));
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
```

Here, `&num` and `&bits` are implicitly converted to a void-pointer, right? Is that ok?

Still... is version 1 REALLY undefined behaviour? I mean to recall some source (which I unfortunately can't link here because I can't find it again) said that the strict aliasing rule only applies when you try to convert to a class type and that reinterpreting between fundamental types is fine. Is this true or total nonsense?

Also... in version 1 I use C-style casting to convert a `uint32_t*` to a `float*`.
I recently learned that C-style casting will just attempt the various types of C++ casts in a certain order (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). Also, I heard I should genereally avoid C-style casts for that reason.

So ***IF*** version 1 was fine, would it be better to just do it like this instead?

```
//Version 3
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    uint32_t bits{0x3dfcb924};
    float num {*reinterpret_cast<float*>(&bits)};
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
```

From my understanding, `reinterpret_cast` is used to convert some pointer to type A to some pointer to type B, "reintepreting" the underlying bits in the process, which is exactly what I want to do. I believed that version 1 did exactly this anyway since the C-style cast will detect that and automatically convert this to a `reintepret_cast`. If that was the case, Version 1 and Version 3 would be identical since they both do `reinterpret_cast`s, only that Version 3 does so explicitly. Is that correct?

So... which one should I use? Version 1, Version 2 or Version 3? And why?

All three versions seem to work on my machine by the way.

EDIT: Forgot to mention... if Version 3 WAS undefined behaviour, what is the point of `reinterpret_cast` then anyway? I looked at this post:

[When to use reinterpret_cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast)

But I didn't really find an answer that I understood. So... what is `reinterpret_cast` good for then?

Comment: _"which one should I use?"_ - `memcpy` to a `char[sizeof(float)]` then from that to the actual `float` target.

Comment: version1 IS UB, you have to use `memcpy` or `bitcast`.

Comment: *"All three versions seem to work"* That is the problem with UB, "seems to work" is a possible behavior...

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't get it. Why is copying to an intermediary char array defined behaviour?

Comment: _"Why is copying to an intermediary char array defined behaviour?"_ - Language design.

Comment: Because the standard explicitly carves out a special exemption for aliasing to char (or `std::byte`).

Comment: @TedLyngmo So, version 2 is also undefined behaviour? But then wouldn't you have to do this EVERY TIME you used std::memcpy in any way?

Comment: @RedBox Yes. All versions have UB. If you do it the way it's defined to work, it'll be optimized away on those platforms where it's not actually needed so, no worries about unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo "If you do it the way it's defined to work, it'll be optimized away on those platforms where it's not actually needed so, no worries about unnecessary overhead. " I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: @TedLyngmo Also, then what is the point of reinterpret_cast? I thought this was its main use case. Why use it at all if it only leads to undefined behaviour?

Comment: @RedBox It means that if you use `memcpy` in your code it may not become an actual call to `memcpy` in assembler. The example implementation of [`bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) seems to suggest that you _can_ copy directly from one to the other (without the intermediate `char[]`). I find that suspicious - but I may be wrong about that. I would have expected something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/oh4vnrhsq). `reinterpret_cast` can't be used here because of the [aliasing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing).

Comment: The point of `reinterpret_cast` is not to defeat the type system, it's when you know something the compiler doesn't, such as round-tripping a pointer through another type. That said, [gcc explicitly supports](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Type%2Dpunning) `union` type-punning.

Comment: @RedBox - *"it'll be optimized away"* means that all compilers know what memcpy'ing 4 bytes means. It doesn't involve calling some function at runtime. The optimizer can do *a lot* better than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of them. Use [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) instead. UB is UB. You can't trust it will work "next time".

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <bit>

int main() {
    uint32_t bits{0x3dfcb924}; //bits describe "0.1234" as IEEE 754 floating point
    float num = std::bit_cast<float>(bits);
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I only have GCC 10, that doesn't support bit_cast. 

Also, certainly there must have been a wy to do this correctly before C++20 existed, right?

Comment: @RedBox No, they were workarounds. Just like old coders used `volatile` to fake thread-safety. It wasn't an actual solution.

Comment: @RedBox Are you stuck on GCC? No way to use something better? (When a compiler still claims "experimental support for C++20" in 2023 I would consider it out-of-date).

Comment: @BoP uhhhh... they just memcpy it?? xD
But you guys said that's undefined behaviour

Comment: @RedBox • Ted's example shows you how to correctly `memcpy` it.

Comment: @RedBox - The example implementation uses [is_trivially_copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) to verify that the types *can* be memcpy'd. Then it is ok.

Comment: @BoP I should mention that I have never tried to do type punning on any non-fundamental types. And I suppose those ought to be trivially copyable.

Answer (score -2):

You could use a `union` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

union floatbits {
    uint32_t bits;
    float fp;
};

int main()
{
    floatbits fb {};
    fb.bits = 0x3dfcb924;  // float 0.1234
    std::cout << fb.fp << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, the whole concept is dependent upon the size of `uint32_t` being the same as `float` and that may not always be true.

Comment: I heard this only works if compiler specific extensions for union punning are enabled. While GCC does have such extensions, I would prefer type punning in a way that is defined behaviour in ISO C++

Comment: This program is ill-formed. It reads from a union field that isn't the active field. The behavior is undefined.